# calling a method that changes nib properties using detachNewThreadSelector

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uikit, thread-safety, nsthread

I' m calling doSaveItems: like

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSaveItems:) toTarget:self withObject:aObject];
```

doSaveItems: method has a code that references to one of my Outlets:

```
[uiProgressLedIdle setHidden:YES];
```

of course I'm setting an autorelease pool inside this method.
The problem is that `[uiProgressLedIdle setHidden:YES];` has no effect on my GUI when I call this method using detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: If I call it [self doSaveItems:aObject] everything is fine and my uiProgressLedIdle is Hidden!
Any suggestion of what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIKit is not thread safe; always make your calls from the main thread.

of course, you're able to use multithreading in iOS - but you push your downloads and other blocking requests to secondary threads. when work is finished, use `performSelectorOnMainThread:` to notify the object responsible for updating the ui objects. this call will happen in the next invocation of the main thread's run loop.